# Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled - which component are they referring to?

Tags: reactjs, post, components, crud

I created a POST feature in my React application. However, I got the below error message:

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled.

If I check in "inspect", the POST does get executed.

Below is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const AddDoc = () => {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState([
    { email: "", first_name: "", last_name: "" },
  ]);
  const { email, first_name, last_name } = profile;

  const postProfile = async newProfile => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(newProfile),
    };
    const response = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users", requestOptions);
    const data = await response.json();
    setProfile(data.id);
  };

  const onChange = change =>
    setProfile({ ...profile, [change.target.name]: change.target.value });

  const onSubmit = submit => {
    submit.preventDefault();
    postProfile(profile);
  };

  return (
    <form className="section" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <h2>Post data</h2>
      <input
        type="email"
        name="email"
        value={email}
        onChange={onChange}
        placeholder="Email"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="first_name"
        value={first_name}
        onChange={onChange}
        placeholder="First name"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="last_name"
        value={last_name}
        onChange={onChange}
        placeholder="Last name"
      />
      <button type="submit">Post</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default AddDoc;
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

It happens because there are no initial values for those inputs. Now, you might wonder how's that? Because you initialized values here:

```
const [profile, setProfile] = useState([
    { email: "", first_name: "", last_name: "" },
  ]);
```

You did that, but you didn't either initialize them correctly or destructured them correctly.

This: `const { email, first_name, last_name } = profile;` is not correct destructuring.
It would be this:

```
const [{ email, first_name, last_name }] = profile;
```

You can initialize your values like this:

```
const [profile, setProfile] = useState({ email: "", first_name: "", last_name: "" });
```

And destructure them properly:

```
const { email, first_name, last_name } = profile;
```

Comment: Completely missed the errant `[]`, good catch. The `setProfile(data.id);` still seems like a mistake though as an FYI to the OP.

Comment: I did that but I'm still getting the same warning